# Is it against the rules of SE to not accept most answers?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

Among the most of the answers I get on my questions, either I do not feel the answer is right, or they are opinion based. Some answers (and comments that support their answers) do not share references.

Or simply I don't get satisfied with the reasons they give.

So I can't accept many answers. (of course there are answers that can be accepted, I'll see them soon). Is it against the rules? Will I be banned soon if I just keep asking and don't accept any answer?

Comment: I don't think it's against the rules.

Comment: @Random-15 wouldn't it be *adharma* to not accept them?

Comment: @Vikas Hinduism Stack Exchange is not a Hindu site but a site about Hinduism. So, Stack Exchange doesn't recognize what's dharma according to Hinduism. It's all about Stack Exchange Question Answer Model.

Comment: @Paṇḍyā okay so can I ask this as a question on main site? Whether it is dharma or adharma?

Comment: @Vikas Well, it would be closed as either opinion based or off-topic since the modern things and technology issues are not mentioned in scripture nor preached by Acharyas.

Comment: @Vikas The dharma shastra of SE is Code of Conduct and Dharma sutra is help center. Make sure you follow them. Your question is should you accept an answer you got. This is question about site itself. It belongs to Meta and you've chose right place to ask. Even if you've asked it on main, it will be again migrated to meta. It's off-topic for that reason and not because of the reason Pandya stated.

Comment: @Pandya Really primarily opinion based or off- topic because acharyas didn't preach technology? Since when questions about the site function are closed as POB or off-topic with the reason you've mentioned? Who came up with that close reason?

Comment: Some people here really really hate (or somehow obsessed with) the words Gurus and Acharyas, just because they feel we all Indians follow them, even when we don't follow them blindly.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma It's in the sense that OP is asking whether it's Dharma or not.

Comment: @Paṇḍyā That would be still off-topic for main site because it is a question about site functioning. Whether acharyas talked or not is irrelevant. It is just like "Which tag to use for a XYZ question". This question will be closed as off-topic and migrated to meta and not POB.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Accepting an answer is [completely voluntary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119198/). You won't be banned even if you don't accept one answer. There's no obligation for people to accept answers.

From [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/):

> ### Which answer should I accept?
>
> - Don't hesitate to accept an answer that is well-written, suggests a good practice and works for you.
> - Otherwise, even if there are answers that are *good enough* but that you're not entirely satisfied by, you might wait 24 to 48 hours to
>     give other people a chance to give you a better answer. A question
>     with an accepted answer isn't as likely to receive further attention
>     as one without an accepted answer.
> - Make sure that besides working for you, the answer is also good for others to follow. Sometimes after the answer gets accepted, another
>     comes in, uncovering the fact that previous one was in fact not the
>     perfect way.
> - **The bottom line is that you should accept the answer that you found to be the most helpful to you, personally.**
>
> ### What should I do if none of the answers are suitable?
>
> - Re-read your question critically and make certain that it's clear what the problem is, and what the specific question is. You might want
>     to place a bold single sentence version of your question at the bottom
>     of your post to make sure it's clear what's being asked.
> - Re-read the answers. Consider accepting the best answer of the bunch, even if none of them are exactly what's needed.
> - Wait a few days after asking it, and then edit your question with what you've learned since asking it — perhaps additional
>     information will help others help you. This will also have the effect
>     of bringing your question back onto the homepage where fresh eyes can
>     see it.
> - If you have **at least 75** reputation, you can add a bounty two days after the question is asked. This will place your question in
>     the "Featured Questions" list, and it will be more visible. A bounty
>     will also add incentive for people to answer your question.
> - Eventually you'll resolve the problem or find a work-around (which may be, "This won't work, so here's what I did instead"). Please add
>     an answer with this information and accept your own answer so that
>     others with your same question can see the path you eventually
>     followed. This is also applicable if no one answer helped you, but you
>     instead combined information from multiple answers.

So, in short, you don't need to accept an answer if you are not satisfied.

Comment: But I guess not accepting would be *adharma*?

Comment: @Vikas Haha, Adharma for not giving virtual reputation? You might tend to say thanks for efforts but such comments will be considered as noise and deleted. It is perfectly fine as per SE and it is status-by-design.

Comment: Saying thanks is noise? Never knew that. I always do that!

Comment: @Vikas - Very good question. But let me clear one thing about the answering part that  is , users here are writing answers from the free time they are getting from their work and personal life and are not engage in this activity for the  full time.  .Finding and writing an exact answer is not easy as you are thinking ,So considering time limit and the complexity of questions , its not fair to  Expect too much from an  answer. Anyway users here are trying to help with best they can . This is what SE expects us to do. Appreciating a good answer is what you are expected from your side

Comment: If you are the Questioner. But not accepting answers deliberately is also not considered decent behaviour if it covers all the points in answer.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar it's not like I'm deliberately not accepting them. Also, to appreciate them, I do up vote.

Comment: You are encouraged by the site to accept that's why they give you +2 each time you accept an answer but it's not compulsory. But some users never accept any answers even though some of the answers they got are quite good. Now, this might be discouraging for the answer writers. @Vikas

Comment: @Rickross yeah I understand. That's why, I'll accept some of the answers I have got, once I take a look upon them again.